# Google Analytics Absolute Change Sort in Custom Reports

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem with my Custom Reports in Google Analytics. I'm trying to compare periods but it seems impossible to use Absolute Change sort within Custom Reports. Instead, the same option is available in classic reports. Is absolute change sort option available for custom report? Thank you in advance for your help.

**Edit:**  Unfortunately I can't attach any photo, but I will try to explain better. As you surely know in Google Analytics I can compare data with a previous period. Analytics allows the user to sort the compared data through several Sort Types. There are three Sort Types available: Default, Absolute Change and Weighted. Each one of these takes into account different algorithms to sort data. You can switch to a different sort type just by using the drop-down menu placed beside "Secondary Dimension", above the results table.  So, I checked out that In Custom Reports the "Absolute Change" option is never made available: when I try to switch from Default to Absolute type, the entry "Absolute Change" is disabled, so I can't select it. It seems to be a trivial feature of Analytics, and I'm not sure whether it is a limitation of custom reports, or maybe if I configured something wrong.

Comment: Unclear what are you asking?

Comment: Just updated the question, I hope it is clearer now

Comment: Same problem for me... I solved exporting data and using Excel to compare absolute change. I hope that there may be a better solution!